# Error in hair texture

Tags: texturing, hair

I need some help.

I have hair in blender with a texture, when I export to an external game it gets with invisible faces as image, have any options that I can change it? Anyone know anything about?

Thank you...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely the issue is causedby seeing the backside of your meshes Normals. This causes it to appear invisible if you aren't looking at the faces from the front. One way to prevent this is to take your mesh, duplicate it, then flip the normals so that you can see it from both sides. Here is some documentation explaining different ways of going about this.

http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/double-sided-faces-different-materials.php

It is possible however, enable Double sided in Properties > Object Data > Normals. But this uses considerably more resources to render than a mesh alone.

Comment: As far as I know you flip Normals, not UVs, if you flip UVs you will get upside-down textures. The *Double Sided* option is a Blender Internal/Game Engine specific thing, it will not work in other render engines, much less in external applications

Comment: Ah sorry my bad I meant to say Normals I will correct this. thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Nathan, Duarte, thank you very much for the tips, they solved the problem.